# Показать/ скрыть меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть меню, по клику оно с лева выезжает и исчезает. Сейчас добился только открытия, помогите составить верно проверку, чтобы его закрывать. 
[Пример](https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/RjvOGP)

```js
$('#but').click(function() {
  $('.nav').addClass('open');
  // $('.nav').addClass('close');
});
```

```css
.rc {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#but {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  width: 30vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30vw;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: left .3s ease;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.open {
  left: 0;
}

.close {
  left: -30vw !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rc">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <button id="but">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: используй `toggleClass`

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#but').click(function() {
  $('.nav').toggleClass('open');

});
```

```css
.rc {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#but {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  width: 30vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30vw;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: left .3s ease;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.open {
  left: 0;
}

.close {
  left: -30vw !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rc">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <button id="but">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#but').click(function() {
  $('.nav').toggleClass('open');
  // $('.nav').addClass('close');
});
```

```css
.rc {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#but {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  width: 30vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30vw;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: left .3s ease;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.open {
  left: 0;
}

.close {
  left: -30vw !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rc">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <button id="but">Button</button>
</div>
```